# Why php scripts lauched from the browser are executed only one?

Tags: php, ubuntu, mozilla, chromium, linphone

I wrote a php script, I executed it from mozilla (or chromium) and the first time all is ok (I'm trying to have a voip call with linphonecsh, a virtual phone). But if I execute it a second time, it doesn't work. I must reboot the virtual machine (ubuntu).. From terminal instead I can execute my script lots of time without problem. Any suggestion?
PHP Script:

```
 <?php
$output1=shell_exec ("linphonecsh init");
sleep(1);
echo "INIT done<br>";
$output2=shell_exec ("linphonecsh register --host sip:sip.linphone.org --username        
sip:matpc --password 123123");
sleep(2);
echo "REGISTRATION done<br>";
$a= shell_exec("linphonecsh status register");
echo $a;
echo "<br>";
sleep(1);
$output=shell_exec ("linphonecsh dial sip:mat99@sip.linphone.org");
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: sounds like a major memory leak... Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068301/how-to-find-which-php-script-is-leaking-memory can help

Comment: Can you post the PHP script?

Comment: Patrick: Thanks, I'll try to apply the commands in your link now.

mopo922: Sure, I am editing the post

Comment: SOLVED: I had to kill the active linphonec process!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to kill the active linphonec process with command pkill